# C++ How may I return an array class member of a nested class?

Tags: c++, arrays, reference, return, nested-class

This is not a real question, since I've already solved the problem myself, but I still need some clarifications about the mechanism behind assigning an array's address to a pointer of the same type when the array is a class member of a nested class.

The following code is fully functioning, although it may lack some error_check. It is only meant to show how I made my (real) program work.

---

### HEADER (linkedList)

```
class linkedList
{
public:
    linkedList();
    ~linkedList();
    int* getArray();
    void forward();

private:
    class listNode
    {
    public:
        listNode();
        ~listNode();

        friend class linkedList;

    private:
        int array[3];
        listNode* next;
    };

    listNode *first;
    listNode *current;
};
```

---

### CPP (linkedList)

```
linkedList::linkedList()
{
    first = new listNode;
    current = first;
}
//~~~~~~~~~~~~
linkedList::~linkedList()
{
    delete first;
    first = 0;
    current = 0;
}
//~~~~~~~~~~~~
int* linkedList::getArray()
{
    if (current)
    {
        return &(current->array[0]);
    }
}
//~~~~~~~~~~~~
void linkedList::forward()
{
    if (current->next)
    {
        current = current->next;
    }
}

//-------------------------
//-------------------------
//-------------------------
linkedList::listNode::listNode()
{
    next = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){array[i]=((i+1)*3);}
}
//~~~~~~~~~~~~
linkedList::listNode::~listNode()
{

}
```

---

### CPP (main)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "linked_list.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    linkedList list;

    int *myArray;

    myArray = list.getArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){cout << myArray[i] << " ";}/**/cout << "\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The real program is meant to move through a linked list made of nodes which contain 3 integer values in an array of int type, retrieve the three values and use them as parameters for some other functions.

Now, to do so I have to `return` the address to the first element of the array contained in the node through an accessor.
Apparently, the only way to do it is by returning the reference to the first element of the array in the node to which the `linkedList`'s member variable `current` points to:
`return &(current->array[0]);`.

Why?

I've got to this solution through trial and error with very little knowlegde of the reasons that brought me to build this expression as it is.
Usually, when you want to assign the address of an array to a pointer, you just do so:

```
int main()
{
    int array[3];
    int* pArray;

    pArray = array;
}
```

And that's it, because the name of the array itself is enough to retrieve the address of its first element.

The exact same result can be achieved by doing this (tested):

```
int main()
{
    int array[3];
    int* pArray;

    pArray = &(array[0]);
}
```

Both methods are also valid when the accessor returns the address from a member variable of its own class.

But why, when accessing the member variable of a nested class, I'm forced to use the second method?
What are the logic stages that make it the only viable method?

Comment: This is a terrible way to implement an object around an array - you're basically allowing full, uncontrolled access to your (otherwise private) array by publishing its address - in any substantial program this will lead to all kinds of errors. You should consider using proper encapsulation to hide private values.

Comment: I was able to get your code to work after changing getArray to return current->array. So at least with g++ I am not "forced to use the second method".

Comment: @DavidCullen I am forced. My IDE gives me a compile time error about a type mismatch, if I use `current->array` instead of `&(current->array[0])`. Maybe IDE's fault?

Comment: @xxbbcc I need a direct access to the real data, not to a copy. Anyway, if you know of a better way to do it without exposing the address, I'm all ears, I'm always eager to learn something new and more functional/efficient.

Comment: @ZehryoKarham I think we can safely blame whatever compiler is used by your IDE. As long as I have been programming, &(current->array[0]) has been equivalent to current->array. What brain damaged IDE are you using so we'll all know to avoid it?

Comment: @DavidCullen The IDE is Qt Creator version 5.5, but the compiler is MinGW (the free version of Qt Creator requires external compiler/debugger). Actually, it is also giving me another strange error that doesnt make much sense....but it's not related to the topic.

Answer (score 0):

> But why, when accessing the member variable of a nested class, I'm forced to use the second method?

You aren't:

```
return current->array;
```

and

```
return &(current->array[0]);
```

Both do the same thing when the return type is `int*`. You aren't forced to use the second way.

Also, there's a bug in `getArray`. You don't return anything if `current` is null.

To be pedantic...

> Apparently, the only way to do it is by returning the *reference* to the first element of the array in the node to which the linkedList's member variable current points to:
>   return &(current->array[0]);.

You're returning the address i.e. a pointer. Reference means something else.

Comment: Strange....when I google "c++ references variables", &var is what I get....did I get something wrong, from the many manuals and tutorials I've read all around?
Anyway I am forced, because returning `current->array` and assigning it to an `int*` gives me an error about type mismatch.
Could it be IDE's fault?

Comment: @ZehryoKarham You'll need to find better tutorials or pay closer attention. There are no references there. If the IDE tells you there's an error, then it's likely IDE's fault. I wouldn't be surprised. I haven't seen a single code analyzer that understands c++ completely. If the compiler stops on an error, then the compiler might have a bug.